# How to control JSON serialization result from same POJO?

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a Spring Boot based application with Jackson for JSON serialization/deserizalization and JodaTime for LocalDate object.

I have a User class :

```
public class User {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String email;

    private LocalDate birthday;

    // constructor, getter, setter...
}
```

I have two webservices which don't expose same fields.

For example:

- WS1 will expose all fields and translate birthday in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format;
- WS2 will expose only firstname, lastname and birthday fields and translate birthday in the "yyyy/MM/dd" format.

It will give me something like this:

```
public class View {
    public interface Default {}
    public interface All extends Default {}
}

public class User {

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private String firstname;

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private String lastname;

    @JsonView(View.All.class)
    private String email;

    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    private LocalDate birthday;
}

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/ws1/user")
    @JsonView(View.All.class)
    public User userSeenByWS1() {
        return new User("john", "doe", "john.doe@unknown.com", LocalDate.now());

        /*
        Must return {"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe","email":"john.doe@unknown.com","birthday":"2017-07-27"}
        */
    }


    @RequestMapping("/ws2/user")
    @JsonView(View.Default.class)
    public User userSeenByWS2() {
        return new User("john", "doe", "john.doe@unknown.com", LocalDate.now());

        /*
        Must return {"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe","birthday":"2017/07/27"}
        */
    }
}
```

For now, I know that I can control fields serialization with @JsonView annotation and I can create two different ObjectMapper to control LocalDate serialization. But I don't know how to pass to the @JsonView the well defined objectMapper for each webservice.

I don't want to create 2 DTOs which represent each view of my User class. I want something that I can configure via annotation.